# ¡AHORRA! Con la cuesta abajo de LIDL"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿qué significa "con la cuesta abajo" en "[AHORRA! Con la cuesta abajo de LIDL](https://super-chollos.com/rebajas-lidl/)"? Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2):

¿**Qué significa "con la cuesta abajo**" en " **¡AHORRA! Con la cuesta abajo de LIDL** "?

---

Este es un mensaje típico de marketing en el que se lanza la idea de ayudar a las familias anunciando una rebaja, a veces importante en el precio de algunos productos y que es usual observarlos en periodos determinados del año.

Para comprender el anuncio hay que averiguar y entender el contexto. En este sentido, este anuncio es de hace unos cinco meses aproximadamente, es decir, a últimos de Enero o principios de Febrero.

En España, habitualmente el periodo de las primeras semanas de comienzo del nuevo año recibe el nombre de "Cuesta de Enero" y figurativamente es una "Cuesta hacia arriba", las familias se encuentran en exceso abrumadas por los gastos realizados en las semanas previas debido a los regalos de "Reyes" y el desembolso extra que se realiza en Navidad, por lo que Enero, y parte de Febrero incluso, esta dentro de la mentalidad de inicio del año y una idea colectiva de ese esfuerzo que supone recuperar la normalidad después de cierta dificultad e indudable fatiga económica. Este periodo coincide con las "Grandes Rebajas".

En este sentido el anuncio " ¡**AHORRA! Con la cuesta abajo de LIDL**, está indicando a las familias que aunque estemos en "la cuesta arriba o cuesta de Enero", podrás economizar bastantes recursos que te ayuden a superar estas primeras semanas del año ahorrando, convirtiendo la "Cuesta de Enero", "Cuesta arriba", en una "Cuesta abajo" o "Cuesta hacia abajo", representada por los precios de esta cadena y que ayudan, en esta propaganda, a suavizar y llevar mejor la carga de las familias para que está "Cuesta de Enero" no sea tan gravosa.

Incluso ese descuento puede llegar en algunos artículos hasta el 50% si la compra se realiza "on line" y se adquieren los formatos "XXL", es decir, los más grandes. Espero que lo hayas entendido.

Answer (score 0):

"Cuesta arriba" (opposite of "cuesta abajo") is said about something that is hard. In that context, "Ahorra con la cuesta abajo de LIDL" should mean that it's easy to save money (because of cheap prices).

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente, si lees atentamente esta publicidad, no verás ninguna referencia a la *cuesta abajo* del titular.

En realidad, es solo un *gancho publicitario*, un reclamo, que no está asociado a ningún contenido.

La verdad es esta: dado que **cuesta arriba** es un concepto negativo ---conocido por todos--- la empresa hace un uso capcioso de su opuesto, **cuesta abajo**, para que caigamos y piquemos en el anzuelo. Pero en realidad, en este caso, no significa nada, porque la referida "cuesta abajo", como digo, sólo aparece en el titular.

En pocas palabras: es un truco de marketing (mercadotecnia), que no tiene desarrollo en el texto.